# Is there any way to speed up how often node-tail (https://github.com/lucagrulla/node-tail) checks for changes in a file?

Tags: node.js

I am developing a typscript discord bot using nodejs. I want to use the [node-tail](https://github.com/lucagrulla/node-tail) to read Minecraft log files and send them to the discord server. I have it set up correctly and it works wonderfully, however the delay between sending data to the file and receiving it from the tail takes about 3 seconds. This is too long, so I was wondering if there was a way to speed up how often it checks for changes to a file.

Also, what is a good speed to set the option to (assuming there is one)?

Edit: Here is the code:

```js
import { Config } from "../config";
import { Tail } from "tail"
import { Bridges } from "./bridge";
import { existsSync } from "fs";

export module Tails {
  export function init(server : Config.Server) {

    if (existsSync(server.local_log_file_path)) {
        const tail = new Tail(server.local_log_file_path, {useWatchFile: true})
        const bridge = Bridges.getFromName(server.name);
        console.log(`Tailing log file in '${server.name}'`);

        tail.on("line", (line: string) => {
        if (!bridge) return;
        bridge.emit("minecraft", line);
        });

        tail.on("error", (error: any) => {
          console.log("Error when tailing log file: " + error);
        });
    } else {
      console.log("Error: Could not find log file : " + server.local_log_file_path);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, include your code where you tail.

Comment: [You could try the `flushAtEOF` parameter](https://github.com/lucagrulla/node-tail#constructor-parameters) - it *might* help. But I suspect it's not the tailing that's slow - perhaps the *writing* of the file is. It's a common problem with other tailing mechanisms - if the changes to the file are buffered by the OS or whatever is writing them, then the read will have to wait for the buffer to flush. EDIT: also, possibly try `useWatchFile` set to true.

Comment: @DanMacák Just edited to include code

Comment: @VLAZ I'm pretty sure it is the tail because when I use [tail-file-node](https://github.com/logdna/tail-file-node) and set the time in between checks to 200ms, there is basically no delay in between sending the message and receiving it on discord

Comment: Then try the two parameters I mentioned. They seem like the only ones that might affect the speed.

Comment: Does using the `follow` option help?

Comment: @DanMacák `follow` is to help with log rotations, not the speed of reading. `tail -f logfile.log` will only tail *that one file*. If the file is moved or renamed, e.g., changed to `logfile-2021-07-29.log` at midnight and a new `logfile.log` is started, then `tail` will keep following `logfile-2021-07-29.log` which isn't useful because it's essentially archived, nothing new will be written there. `tail -F logfile.log` (which the `follow` parameter says it emulates) will instead only look for at `logfile.log` even if that file is changed with a new one at the rollover.

Comment: @VLAZ I do already use the useWatchFile parameter, but I will get back to you about flushAtEOF tomorrow.

Comment: @Syntro if you have `useWatchFile: true`, then try adding `fsWatchOptions: { interval: 200 }` (or whatever interval number you want - it's in milliseconds)

Comment: @VLAZ you are right. I thought that it might help since GNU follow also does *output appended data as the file grows* (from `man tail`) but when I looked up the node-tail's code it really only has an effect upon file-rename event. And of course it wouldn't make sense if the `follow` option would help anyway.

Comment: @VLAZ that worked. Thank you very much. One more question, what would be a good time to set it to? I was thinking every second, but wanted to get other people's opinions

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ whatever you feel like. Depends on how fast you want to be getting the changes. Every second might be OK. Every half a second might also be. Perhaps even every 10 milliseconds. Depends on what your circumstances are.